# On form submission add timestamp with current value when row inserted to the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

What I'm trying to do is, when a row on the database has been submitted, a value with the current timestamp to be recorded. 
I initially tried to add this to my entity class:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SubmitedTime", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date submitedTime;
```

But I got an exception saying that submitted time doesn't have a default value.
How do I achieve this ?
I am using Spring boot and mysql as database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Entity Listeners](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) for this.

```
@PrePersist
public void preSave() {
    submittedTime = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in my projects by doing the following:

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
```